# Spawned image from image detection is "glued" to the screen if image/anchor is lost

Tags: unity-game-engine, augmented-reality

So in Unity I´m trying to make an AR app that spawns something after detecting a certain Image. If the camera looses track of the image or the object, it glues the spawned object to the screen though. How can I avoid that and is there a variable that shows the state?

I already tried the "TrackingState" variable which sadly didn´t work. "Limited did not only applied to the state of being glued (to the screen) but also "impaired" which causes the object to despawn even though it´s still shown properly. This sadly leads to very sensitive camera handling, so it is not an option so far.
"None" on the other hand never appeared.

Could anybody please name other elements I could use to fix this problem? Or explain what I´m doing wrong with "TrackingState"?

Here the code I tried so far (I also had a logger to show in which state it is every half second):

```cs
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;
using UnityEngine.XR;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARFoundation;
using UnityEngine.XR.ARSubsystems;

public class ImagesToFigures : MonoBehaviour
{
    private ARTrackedImageManager _arTrackedImageManager;
    private ARManager _arManager;
    private GameObject spawnedObject;
    private string existingString;
    private bool isActive;

    private GameObject[] children;
    private FoundStickerEvent foundStickerEvent;
    private string addedSticker = "";

    private XRReferenceImage referenceImage;



    void Awake()
    {
        _arTrackedImageManager = GetComponentInParent<ARTrackedImageManager>();
        // if (GetComponentInParent<ARManager>()) {
        _arManager = GetComponentInParent<ARManager>();
        // }
        existingString = "";

        children = new GameObject[this.transform.childCount];

        for (int i = 0; i < this.transform.childCount; i++)
        {
            GameObject child = this.transform.GetChild(i).gameObject;
            children[i] = child;
        }
    }

    public void activate()
    {
        isActive = true;
    }

    public void OnEnable()
    {
        _arTrackedImageManager.trackedImagesChanged += OnImageChanged;
    }

    public void OnDisable()
    {
        _arTrackedImageManager.trackedImagesChanged -= OnImageChanged;
    }

    public void destroySpawnedObject()
    {
        // existingString = "";
        foreach (var child in children)
        {
            child.SetActive(false);
        }
        // addedSticker = "";
        // GameManager.instance.log("destroyed");
    }

    private void OnImageChanged(ARTrackedImagesChangedEventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        if (GameManager.instance.currentState == GameState.AR_SCANNING)
        {
            // GameManager.instance.log(eventArgs.updated.Count +" " + referenceImage.name);
            foreach (GameObject child in children)
            {
                if (addedSticker == "")
                {
                    foreach (ARTrackedImage trackedImage in eventArgs.added)
                    {
                        addedSticker = trackedImage.referenceImage.name;
                        // GameManager.instance.log(addedSticker);
                    }
                }
                else
                {
                    // GameManager.instance.log(eventArgs.updated.Count.ToString());
                    foreach (ARTrackedImage trackedImage in eventArgs.updated)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            if (child.name == trackedImage.referenceImage.name &&
                                (child.name == addedSticker || (referenceImage.name == trackedImage.referenceImage.name && child.name == referenceImage.name))
                            )
                            {
                                if (trackedImage.trackingState == TrackingState.Tracking /*|| trackedImage.trackingState == TrackingState.Limited*/)
                                {
                                    child.SetActive(true);
                                    GameManager.instance.currentState = GameState.AR_SCANNED;
                                    GameManager.instance.log(trackedImage.referenceImage.name);
                                    referenceImage = trackedImage.referenceImage;

                                    // GameManager.instance.log(child.transform.position.ToString());
                                    // trackedImage.destroyOnRemoval = true;
                                    _arManager.foundStickerEvent.Invoke(trackedImage.referenceImage.name);
                                    // _arManager.displayInfosEvent.Invoke("Tippe auf die Figur für spannende Infos!");

                                }
                            }
                            // else
                            // {
                            //     child.SetActive(false);
                            // }
                        }
                        catch (Exception e)
                        {
                            GameManager.instance.log("error: " + e.ToString());
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

if ((currentlyActiveImage.trackingState == TrackingState.None) || currentlyActiveImage.trackingState == TrackingState.Limited))
{
  GameManager.instance.destroyARObject();
  GameManager.instance.ResetState();
}
```

Comment: Could you add your code? You probably would want something like `OnTrackingLost` -> `SetActive(false)` or `Destroy` you object ...

Comment: I added the code I had so far. Would you please link the documentation for "OnTrackingLost"? Or tell me where I can find that?

Comment: Please add a complete reproducible code ... we have no clue what library/script etc you are using for doing `after detecting a certain Image` ...

Comment: Added the script, that is called after detection. I´m using the ARFoundation Imagetracking.

Answer (score 0):

In the Tracked Image scripts, you can define what happens when you lose track. Then you can wether set the object to non-active ar destroy it, depending on your needs.